# How do I handle this buggy program in pexpect?

Tags: python, shell, expect, io-redirection, pexpect

I use pexpect to automate a program called instantmusic. Sometimes, this program sends an eof before it has actually finished. Here is a screenshot (If you can’t read the screenshot, I have linked to my more detailed bug report at the end of the question.):
[image]

I can detect the appropriate ending by using this code:

```
child.expect(
        ['Deleting*(pass -k to keep)*', pexpect.EOF], timeout=3000)
```

However, my problem is that pexpect doesn’t catch the output beyond the eof. (Btw, not using that “pexpect.EOF” makes pexpect throw an exception when it encounters EOF.)

Is there a way to handle this problem?

PS: I have described this bug in more detail [here](https://github.com/yask123/Instant-Music-Downloader/issues/135). But I generally like to be able to handle this situation even if the source program IS buggy. Since it seems to me that it should be possible.

Comment: Please don't only post the screenshot picture.

Comment: @EmilyE. The screenshot is not necessary to get the problem, and I have linked to my complete bug report if you do think it’s necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the pattern needs to be a regular expression, so would this be better?

```
child.expect(['Deleting.*\(pass -k to keep\)', pexpect.EOF], timeout=3000)
# .....................^^^................^
```

It seems that pexpect does not implement the tcl expect glob-style patterns.

Comment: I don’t think this is the problem since it works correctly most of the time (the underlying bug in the source application appears only rarely). “.*” might not work in fact. Idk. I haven’t tried.